# With Ruby on Rails, how do I create an ActiveRecord migration with a default value for datetime of January 1st, 2004

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here is my migration

```
class AddUpdateStartedAtToToUserMappings < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     add_column :user_mappings, :update_started_at, :datetime, default: DateTime.now
   end 
end
```

I want the default to be January 1st, 2004 not DateTime.now

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change:

```
DateTime.now
```

to

```
DateTime.new(2004, 1, 1)
```